# Joining tables where the column names are different

Tags: mysql

I'm using WP eCommerce plugin and have the following tables

**Table 1 wp_wpsc_cart_contents**

```
|id|quantity|name      |purchaseid|price|custom_message|

|22|1       |black ... |46        |19.45|nickname 1    |
|23|1       |red ...   |47        |19.45|nickname 2    |
```

**Table 2 wp_wpsc_submited_form_data**

```
|id|log_id|form_id|value        |

|1 |46    |2      |email 1      |
|2 |46    |12     |first name 1 |
|3 |46    |13     |last name 1  |
|4 |47    |2      |email 2      |
|5 |47    |12     |first name 2 |
|6 |47    |13     |last name 2  |
```

**Desired table:**

```
|name    |log_id/purchaseid|price|quantity|value                    |

|black ..|46               |19.45|1       |email1, f-name 1, l-name 1|
|red ... |47               |19.45|1       |email2. f-name 2, l-name 2|
```

I've had limited success with the following 2 queries, but cannot work out how to join the tables — given that the matching data is in differently named columns and the 'value' data I'm trying to select is in different rows

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents 
WHERE name LIKE '%$term%'
ORDER BY name

SELECT *, value, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', ') value
FROM wp_wpsc_submited_form_data
GROUP BY log_id
ORDER BY log_id
```

Screenshots:

[image: wp_wpsc_cart_contents.PNG]
[image: wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.PNG]

Answer (score 1):

try this query...

```
    create table desired_table_name as SELECT w.name,w.log_id, w2.price, w.quantity, 
    w2.value FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents w inner join wp_wpsc_submited_form_data w2 on 
    w.log_id=w2.purchaseid WHERE w.name LIKE '%$term%'  ORDER BY w.name
```

Comment: Ran your query in myphpadmin and got Unknown column 'w.log_id' in 'field list'

Comment: Also - trying to print to table using php rather than do query in myphpadmin

Comment: create table desired_table_name as SELECT w.name,w2.log_id, w2.price, w.quantity, 
    w2.value FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents w inner join wp_wpsc_submited_form_data w2 on 
    w2.log_id=w.purchaseid WHERE w.name LIKE '%$term%'  ORDER BY w.name

Comment: ifthe query will give u right, what u want then try wid php

Comment: Sure! and thanks so far. That query in phpMyadmin returned Unknown column 'w2.price' in 'field list' Am I doing the right thing running this query on the Wordpress database for this Wordpress installation?

Comment: actuall i'm familiar wid mysql as u can try with some ltl changes like put as keyword while giving alias .

Comment: I'm afraid you've lost me there! Way over my head

Comment: I decided in my novice way to expand the table names to full, like so: create table desired_table_name as SELECT wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name,wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.log_id, wp_wpsc_cart_contents.price, wp_wpsc_cart_contents.quantity, wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.value FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents inner join wp_wpsc_submited_form_data on wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.log_id=wp_wpsc_cart_contents.purchaseid WHERE wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name The query ran ok but created an empty tabe

Comment: Aha! Just got this to work -- SELECT wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name,wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.log_id, wp_wpsc_cart_contents.price, wp_wpsc_cart_contents.quantity, wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.value FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents inner join wp_wpsc_submited_form_data on wp_wpsc_submited_form_data.log_id=wp_wpsc_cart_contents.purchaseid WHERE wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name LIKE '%$term%' ORDER BY wp_wpsc_cart_contents.name -- could do with concatinating the 'value' entries to stop repeats, but MANY thanks - getting there!!

Answer (score 0):

Your second query should be simplified a bit to get most of what you want:

```
SELECT log_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', ') value
  FROM wp_wpsc_submited_form_data
 GROUP BY log_id
```

You can then use this as 'table' in the other query:

```
SELECT c.name, c.purchaseid, c.price, c.quantity, f.value  
  FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents AS c
  JOIN (SELECT log_id AS purchase_id, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', ') value
          FROM wp_wpsc_submited_form_data
        GROUP BY log_id) AS f
    ON c.purchase_id = f.purchase_id
 WHERE name LIKE '%$term%'
 ORDER BY name
```

Also, there are two t's in 'submitted'.